# Is it possible to select which folders to sync in OneDrive (Skydrive) on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, onedrive, selection

Is it possible to select which folders to sync in OneDrive (formerly Skydrive) on Windows 8.1?

(I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro)

This is possible in Windows 7 version of SkyDrive, but can't see setting in Windows 8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Windows 8.1 uses ["smart files"](http://blogs.windows.com/skydrive/b/skydrive/archive/2013/09/30/skydrive-introduces-smart-files-in-windows-8-1.aspx) to determine if the files are "online only" or "available offline" - you can do some symbolic linking tricks and change some registry values to do what you want (I think), but the option isn't native.

Check out [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/174765/how-to-sync-any-folder-with-skydrive-on-windows-8.1/) to see if those tricks help you. I can't test it and provide a walk-through as I'm not on 8.1.

Comment: +1 accepted. I can appreciate where they are going with this. Though it would be nice to be able to not sync some folders for more selective privacy, for example. It seems that the privacy is very overall / 'blanket' / global. Sometimes you have others around you while you work at your PC and may want some selective control. Thanks though for conveying the facts.

Comment: Absolutely, the security and privacy options for things like this (cloud) need to be much more granular to allow for more security. That's assuming we believe that the options actually provide security..
It's more about forcing users to choose AND STICK WITH particular software.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done, and no trickery is required. See my answer elsewhere on superuser [here](https://superuser.com/a/719214/3560)

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive does not support junction at this time.

A workaround is to:

- Move your folders to the new location c:\users\you\onedrive
- For example, c:\users\you\documents would be moved to c:\users\you\onedrive\documents
- Check to see if c:\users\you\documents folder is empty
- Erase if empty
- Use junction tool from sysinternals to create a link:

`junction c:\users\you\documents c:\users\you\onedrive\documents`

The location for your documents in now in OneDrive\documents. You just create a link that points to OneDrive\documents.